# obstacle avoidance for astech pelican machines

Tags: ros, uav, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am totally new at this so can any one guide me for algorithms for obstacle avoidance
and any help how to deal with the asetech pelican machines

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12908/obstacle-avoidance-for-astech-pelican--machines/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Obstacle avoidance for aerial vehicles is a huge field and I don't think that there is an answer to this question.

You could use the ROS3D Contest Entry: [Quadrotor Altittude and Obstacle Avoidance](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Quadrotor%20Altitude%20Control%20and%20Obstacle%20Avoidance) as a base for your code.

There are some additional resources for the AscTec Pelican that might get you in the right direction:

- [ROS News: Robots/UAVS](http://www.ros.org/news/robots/uavs/)
- [DIYDrones: Arducopter](http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/wiki/ArduCopter)
- [ROS Robots: AscTec Pelican](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/AscTec)
- [ROS Answers: UAV Simulation Using ROS](http://answers.ros.org/question/101/how-can-uavs-be-simulated-using-ros)
- [ROS Answers: 2D/3D Slam for UAV](http://answers.ros.org/question/865/solutions-for-visually-aided-2d3d-slam-for-uav)
- [ASCTec Pelican Users Mailing List](http://asctec-users.986163.n3.nabble.com/)

You may want to make your question more specific, or else you won't get many answers.

**Possible Duplicates**

- http://answers.ros.org/question/3380/autonomously-flying-quadrotor

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1